# Accessing protected method of anonymous object vs by a named reference

Tags: java

Say I have this **abstract** class:

```java
package test.one;

public abstract class One {
  
  protected abstract void whatever();

  public void run() {
    whatever();
  }
  
}
```

And use it like this:

```java
package test.two;

import test.one.One;

public class Three {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    One one = new One() {
      @Override
      protected void whatever() {
        System.out.println("Do whatever..");
      }
    };
    one.whatever();
  }
}
```

This code **fails on compilation** which is pretty much expected.

```
test/two/Three.java:14: error: whatever() has protected access in One
    one.whatever();
       ^
1 error
```

But **the below code compiles successfully** which seems surprisingly:

```java
package test.two;

import test.one.One;

public class Two {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new One() {
      @Override
      protected void whatever() {
        System.out.println("Do whatever..");
      }
    }.whatever();
  }
}
```

The difference is that in the latter case I'm accessing the method without a named reference. Why does the compiler allow such access?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The difference is that in the latter case I'm accessing the method without a named reference. Why does the compiler allow such access?

No, the difference is that in the latter case you're accessing the method *on the anonymous class* rather than on a reference of type `One`.

Leaving aside the oddities around protected access, you can see the difference very easily by just creating an anonymous class with a public method:

```java
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is fine...
        new Object() {
            public void method() {
                System.out.println("Called");
            }
        }.method();
        
        // This is not, because Object doesn't contain a method called "method".
        Object o = new Object() {
            public void method() {
                System.out.println("Called");
            }
        };
        o.method();        
    }
}
```

As noted in comments, another way to see the same effect is to use `var`, so that the compile-time type of the variable is the anonymous class.

Even private members within anonymous classes can be accessed within the containing scope, just as if they were normal nested classes.

Comment: @luk2302, no he may also access private members as long as he does it within the same statement. You can try it by declaring a private method and accessing it before the end of the statement, you will be able to do so independently on the package you're in.

Comment: Another way to show it is `var one = new One() { /*...*/ }; one.whatever();`, which works because the type of `one` is the anonymous class, not `One`, and (as you said) the anonymous class is in the same package as the containing class.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ: That's interesting - I'll modify my last paragraph...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You say it's because it's in the same package, but `protected` access is not the same as `package-private` (no explicit modifier), so this doesn't explain why the function `main` within class `Two` has access to the protected function `whatever` in the anonymous class. Are we saying that access modifiers on methods (and fields?) within anonymous classes are ignored? Or that they are considered subclasses of the containing class (`Two`) AND the original (`One`)? But that would be multiple inheritance, which Java lacks.

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing a language specification citation for the claim: "Even private members within anonymous classes can be accessed within the containing scope [...]".  (I looked for and failed to find such a provision in JLS 18.)

Comment: @ScottMcPeak [Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared private, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)

Comment: @Corrodias `protected` is *broader* than default visibility, not narrower. It permits access from the same package, and additionally from subclasses in other packages.

Comment: @amalloy Whoa! I'm not sure how I forgot that, but you're right. Maybe I was thinking of how C# does it.